# Automatic Update for database rows based on changes in another table

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have a scenario that requires a value in a row of a table to be updated automatically whenever a row has been added or deleted in another table. I'm not sure how to do it.BTW I'm using phpmyadmin in order to manage my database. Thanks in advance.

```
pages Table
------------
page_no
no_of_choices

choices Table
-------------
page_no
choice_no
```

When I add a choice with choice number 1 and page_no, then the table page which has the row, page_no=1 should be updated with no_of_choices=no_of_choices+1

Comment: This can be accomplished using mysql JOIN's aswell as primary and foreign keys ... I'd type out a better answer for you but im brushing up on the the exact details myself ... but at least its a starting point for you

Comment: Can that be used for count too. I have a case where value of one row element is equal to value of no of elements with some identity in another table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use triggers.

For example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `test1` 
AFTER INSERT ON `tbl1`
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.upd_fld =  new_value
```

Similarly could be done for delete.

You can also create triggers from phpMyAdmin

Comment: Hi Rohini, I actually wanted to +1 or -1 to the existing value inside a row.

Comment: Can u explain your requirement with a supportive example.

Comment: Is there any relationship between both the tables?

Answer (score 0):

TABLE A: page_no, no_of_choices
TABLE B: page_no, choice_no...

With a relational database you very rarely want to have duplicate data.  If something breaks at some point, you won't know which to trust - the rows in Table B, or the no_of_choices in Table A.  A better solution is to do one of the following (depending on which table you are querying):

`SELECT COUNT(no_of_choices) FROM B WHERE page_no = 1`

or

`SELECT A.*, COUNT(choice_no) AS choice_no FROM A LEFT JOIN B USING(page_no)`

You get the same result, but now you have one record to go off of, so you won't have inconsistent data.